# Distance Calculation from autocomplete

Tags: android

I m trying to calculate distance from Autocomplete. and getting below error

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result)
{
                   // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
}
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap to List>

if I typecase like below

```
 List<HashMap<String, String>> path = (List<HashMap<String, String>>)result.get(i);
```

getting

```
07-22 16:23:52.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12339): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Comment: path should be an HashMap not a List<HashMap

Answer (score 1):

your compiler is telling you everything *`"Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap to List>"`*

you are doing wrong as you are trying to assign `HashMap<String, String>` from `HashMap<String, String>` to `List<HashMap<String, String>>` which is not allowed.

you should use following instead

```
HashMap<String, String> path = result.get(i);
```